# can RDBMS triggers fire db events to message queue

Tags: database, triggers, message-queue, rdbms

Just wondering does RDBMS like mysql, oracle, sqlserver support using triggers to fire the update events to a message queue?

Comment: Don't know what you had in mind, but you just wrote the question exactly the way I just had it in my head +1 year later :-). Did you make any research?

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL call `pg_notify('mychannel', 'my message');` in a trigger

Your message queue, or an intermediary component, would call `LISTEN mychannel` on a connection to the PostgreSQL database, and send a message to the queue.

Looks like there is an extension to publish directly from PostgreSQL to an AMQP message queue (though not active):

https://github.com/omniti-labs/pg_amqp

Answer (score 0):

If using Oracle use AQ (Advanced Queuing) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm